# Concatenate Input Parameter with Column name in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have table in Orcale. Like:

```
ID  |  YEAR  |  Day1  |  Day2  |  Day3  |  Day4  |  Day5 ... to Day31
========================================================
```

I want to update specific day. I have the Day number which i get from date. But how i concatenate the Day number with column 'Day' so i get the column of specific day. If any other way to do this kindly help me.

Thanks,
ByteBoy

Comment: Read about dynamic SQL.

Comment: @byteboy:What have you tried ? and where have you have problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem:

```
CREATE TABLE day_table
(id NUMBER,
 year NUMBER,
 day1 NUMBER,
 day2 NUMBER,
 day3 NUMBER,
 day4 NUMBER,
 day5 NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO day_table VALUES(1, 2014, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_day(p_day_number NUMBER, p_day_value NUMBER) IS
  v_sql VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  v_sql:='UPDATE day_table SET day'||p_day_number||'='||p_day_value;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;

BEGIN
 update_day(3, 666);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

```
create table t1(
   datum date
  ,day1  number, day2  number, day3  number, day4  number, day5  number
  ,day6  number, day7  number, day8  number, day9  number, day10 number
  ,day11 number, day12 number, day13 number, day14 number, day15 number
  ,day16 number, day17 number, day18 number, day19 number, day20 number
  ,day21 number, day22 number, day23 number, day24 number, day25 number
  ,day26 number, day27 number, day28 number, day29 number, day30 number
  ,day31 number
  ,constraint t1_pk primary key(datum)
);

insert into t1(datum)
select date '2014-01-01' - 1 + level as datum
  from dual
  connect by level <= date '2014-12-31' - date '2014-01-01' + 1;

commit;

declare
   l_sql varchar2(1000) := null;
   l_col varchar2(80)   := null;
begin

   for r in (select datum from t1) loop
      l_col := 'day' || to_number(to_char(r.datum, 'DD'));

      l_sql := 'update t1 set ' || l_col || ' = 1 where datum = :d';
      execute immediate l_sql using r.datum;
   end loop;

   commit;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue using Datatable in my Code Behind file.

Thank you so much for your help.